# status 404 on login.html

Tags: tomcat, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have deployed *JasperReports Server* 4.5.0

when i open the URL for login : localhost:5555/jasperserver/login.html
I got 404 status file not found.

When checked in localhost.log, I got the logs:

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'themeSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-themes.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'themeCache' while setting bean property 'themeCache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'themeCache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-themes.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'unsecureRepositoryService' while setting bean property 'repositoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'unsecureRepositoryService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateRepositoryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateRepositoryListeners' while setting bean property 'repositoryListeners'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateRepositoryListeners' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'schedulingReportDeleteListener' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulingReportDeleteListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportSchedulingService' while setting bean property 'schedulingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportSchedulingService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportSchedulingFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportScheduler' while setting bean property 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportQuartzScheduler' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportQuartzScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'quartzScheduler' while setting bean property 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot run without an instance id.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:168)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884)
        at org.springframework.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils.initThemeSource(UiApplicationContextUtils.java:58)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:374)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'themeCache' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-themes.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'unsecureRepositoryService' while setting bean property 'repositoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'unsecureRepositoryService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateRepositoryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateRepositoryListeners' while setting bean property 'repositoryListeners'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateRepositoryListeners' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'schedulingReportDeleteListener' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulingReportDeleteListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportSchedulingService' while setting bean property 'schedulingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportSchedulingService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportSchedulingFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportScheduler' while setting bean property 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportQuartzScheduler' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportQuartzScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'quartzScheduler' while setting bean property 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot run without an instance id.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 43 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'unsecureRepositoryService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateRepositoryService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateRepositoryListeners' while setting bean property 'repositoryListeners'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateRepositoryListeners' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'schedulingReportDeleteListener' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulingReportDeleteListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportSchedulingService' while setting bean property 'schedulingService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportSchedulingService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportSchedulingFacade' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportScheduler' while setting bean property 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'reportQuartzScheduler' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reportQuartzScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'quartzScheduler' while setting bean property 'scheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzScheduler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot run without an instance id.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolv

and so on

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved.

I had done the installation on a fresh machine which was not having the entry for hostname in the /etc/hosts file.
I made an entry in the file and it worked.